# How to redirect after error inside of PassportJS/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

When configuring passport using Express and NodeJS, I am throwing an error if the user has an invalid email address. After this error I would like to redirect to a failure page giving them instructions on how to log in correctly. Is there are a better way to do this? If not, how would I go about catching the error in some fashion and redirecting to a new page.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID     : auth.googleAuth.clientID,
        /* Settings redacted for brevity */
    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne(
            {
                "google.id" : profile.id
            },
            function(err, user) {

                if (err) return done(err)

                if (user) return done(null, user)

                else {

                    if (email.indexOf("lsmsa.edu") > -1) {

                        // Code redacted for brevity

                    } else {
                        done(new Error("Invalid email address"))
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* I quite like BlackMamba's answer as well, adding the custom callback / redirect is a perfectly acceptable option.

Simply add your own error handling middleware to Express:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID     : auth.googleAuth.clientID,
    /* Settings redacted for brevity */
},
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({
            "google.id" : profile.id
        },
        function(err, user) {

            if (err) return done(err)

            if (user) return done(null, user)

            else {

                if (email.indexOf("lsmsa.edu") > -1) {

                } else {
                    // Throw a new error with identifier:
                    done(throw {
                        type: "invalid_email_address", 
                        code: 401, 
                        profileId: profile.id
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    )
}));

// The error handling middleware:

app.use(function(e, req, res, next) {
    if (e.type === "invalid_email_address") {
        res.status(e.code).json({
            error: {
                msg: "Unauthorized access", 
                user: e.profileId
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You'll notice I modified this answer a little bit with a more robust error composition. I've defined the `code` property of the error to match the applicable HTTP status code -- in this case, `401`:

```
// callback
done(throw {
    // just a custom object with whatever properties you want/need
    type: "invalid_email_address",
    code: 401, 
    profileId: profile.id
}));
```

In the error handling, we simply check the type is `invalid_email_address` (you can make it whatever you want, but it should be consistent across your app) and then write the error out using the "code" as the HTTP status code:

```
          // e is the error object, and code is the custom property we defined
res.status(e.code).json({
    error: {
        msg: "Unauthorized access",
        user: e.profileId
    }
});
```

#### Here's a self-contained working example with a redirect:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    throw {type: "unauthorized", code: 401}
})

app.use(function(e, req, res, next) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.code === 401) {
        res.redirect("/login")
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({error: e.type});
    }
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: I like both answers. I will have to think about which one should be accepted. The other answer has more detail but lacked the information about express error handling, which will be very useful to know in the future.

Comment: What is the res.status(e.code).json doing? This might actually be the correct answer. The redirects the other user suggested did not work with the error I was throwing.

Comment: Your code does not run? Says unexpected throw token at throw {

Comment: Thanks but I was asking how to redirect to a specific page after an error. How would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: OK see the last example again - it's got a working redirect in there.

Comment: Okay. Cool. I will mark this as correct, but in the done method I am having to create a new Error for passportjs. Throwing it as an argument gives a syntax error. How would I add that information to a new Error() call.

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/justmoon/15511f92e5216fa2624b) on creating a custom error class. You could try that. Not sure why it won't let you pass an error on the fly.

Comment: My error thing is not working at all. The middleware isn't even being called on the error? I am midlly confused. https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/3860c69e7311b2dc4480

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Maybe that's the problem? I tossed yours into my self-contained example and it works.

Comment: What seriously?! Crazy. Yeah, no idea why it happened that way. If anyone knows...!

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use this:

> Redirects
>
> A redirect is commonly issued after authenticating a request.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

> In this case, the redirect options override the default behavior. Upon
> successful authentication, the user will be redirected to the home
> page. If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
> login page for another attempt.

Or this:

> Custom Callback
>
> If the built-in options are not sufficient for handling an
> authentication request, a custom callback can be provided to allow the
> application to handle success or failure.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Please read the document:
https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/downloads/html/#middleware

Comment: I ended up choosing this answer because it highlights the features Passport already has built in and I feel like it may be a more idiomatic way to handle this specific issue inside of PassportJS. But I also like remus' answer because it gave me insight into Express error handling that I did not have prior. Thank you both.